# Change sum for all records starting from specific record

Tags: mysql, sum

I have table:

```
+-------------+------------+---------+  
| Code        | Num        | Total   |  
+-------------+------------+---------+  
| A           | 5          | 10      |  
+-------------+------------+---------+    
| B           | 7          | 17      |  
+-------------+------------+---------+  
| C           | 8          | 25      |  
+-------------+------------+---------+
```

Now if I want to change Num value for record B from 7 to 9 than total for record B should
be 9 and for record C 27. How to write query that will change all sums starting from specific record?

Comment: Do you mean the total for b should be 19? and can we assume the sum should occur incrementally based on the alphabetic order of code?

Comment: @xQbert, Yes correct; BTW, what's the format code you used to make it look like a table?

Comment: hilight the code and use the {} icon or wrap the text in the back tic ``

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cb1/1/0

```
create table b as 
(Select 'A' as code,5 as num ,10 as total)
UNION
(Select 'B' as code,7 as num ,17 as total)
UNION
(Select 'C' as code,8 as num ,25 as total);

update b set num = 9 where code = 'B';
set @var=5;
Update b 
INNER JOIN 
(Select code, num, b.total, @var:=@var+num as NewTotal from b order by code) c
on c.Code=B.code
set b.total=NewTotal;


select * from b;
```